# Testing iOS 6 apps on devices running iOS7 WITHOUT XCODE 5

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, ios7, xcode5

I upgraded my iPhone4 to iOS7 and can not now test applications on it using Xcode 4.6. I had to download XCode 5 but it is not compatible with my current Mac OS version. How can I Test and Build apps without using XCode5 on my devices running iOS7 +

[For those not being able to install XCode 5 for some reason (like I could not upgrade my macBook Pro to MacOS 10.8.X that is required for XCode5), this is my own answer below to help other developers who faced the same issue.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to upgrade MacOS from 10.7.5 to 10.8.x and that is why I could not install Xcode5 on my MAC. I downloaded Xcode5 but due to incompatibility it can not be installed.

I was able to run app using XCode 4.6 in debug mode on an iPhone 4 with iOS 7
(and can't express enough how happy i got after that)

Steps:

1. Use incompatible Xcode5 (copy it from the dmg image to somewhere else, there will be a cross sign in it) and right click on it and Click "show package contents".
2. Go to **Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs** and copy the iPhoneOS7.0.sdk file in the corresponding folder in Xcode4.6 after showing its package contents.
3. Go to **Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport** and copy the 7.0 and 7.0.3(11B508) file in the corresponding folder in Xcode4.6 after showing package contents.

Now when you open Xcode4.6 your project Base SDK should be 7.0 and if your device is not detected yet, disconnect and reconnect your device so that it starts "getting symbol files from iPhoneXYZ"

Hope this helps someone.

One more important thing, in your scheme Debugger should be set to "LLDB"

Comment: i am getting **ld: file not found: /usr/lib/system/host/libdyld.dylib for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1**
any idea why this happens?
please help me out.

Comment: Hi @CrazyProggrammer The method explained above does only work for running a project on a real device. On Simulator this error is not solvable you ll need iPhone7 Simulator for that and that Simulator is only available in XCode5

Comment: yes i have read on internet but still it also not works for my device as well. it gives me exit code 255 on real device.

Comment: @CrazyProggrammer have you set LLDB in the scheme for debugger?

Answer (score 0):

http://news.softpedia.com/news/Download-iPhone-iPod-IPSW-Manually-Restore-via-iTunes-How-to-136037.shtml

thats the link to restore your iPhone to previous versions of iOS hope it helps